# UIMenuItem not showing in table

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to add a custom action to `UIMenuController` for use of on a `UITableViewCell` and it doesn't appear when the menu is shown.

Edit: Revised code.

[image: Screenshot]
Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [UIMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(test))]
        UIMenuController.shared.update()
    }

    // Table view setup
    // ...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(test)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(test)
    }

    @objc func test() {
        print("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Comment: UIMenuController.menuVisible = true     myMenuController.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDirection.Down
        
        // set rect、view
        myMenuController.setTargetRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view)

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234921/uimenucontroller-not-showing-up-the-menu - you try this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `test` function needs to be in the `UITableViewCell` subclass.
2. You need to implement `canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool` in that `UITableViewCell` subclass and return `return action == #selector(test)`
3. In `UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [UIMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(test))]` change `#selector(test)` to `#selector(YourCellSubclass.test)`.
4. Keep the UITableViewDelegate methods you have in your view controller, and change `|| action == #selector(test)` to `|| action == #selector(YourCellSubclass.test)`

**EDIT:**
Adding working example.

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [UIMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(MyCell.test))]
        UIMenuController.shared.update()

        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "my")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(MyCell.test)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
        // needs to be here
    }

}
```

Cell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(test)
    }

    @objc func test() {
        print("works")
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work. See my edit for my revised code.

Comment: @LakhanMankani I have added working example to my answer.